# Creating New Parse null reference exception

Tags: fitnesse, fit-framework

With the latest update of Fitnesse, a constructor was removed from the Parse class that we were using. We have struggled to utilize the other constructors and have run into null reference exceptions, or improper parsing of the data.

The previous code called the old constructor in this fashion:

```
newRow = new Parse(ReplaceVariablesInRow(row), new string[] { "tr", "td" }, 0, 0);
```

This would result in proper replacement of variables in our fitnesse test (replacing >>var<< with its value ). If the new parse is not created, there is no replacement and the test thinks that the value is ">>var<<". If the one-parameter constructor is called with just a string (could be any), a null reference exception is thrown.

Is there a correct way to call the new parse so that variables can be updated properly or is there a way to modify the current Parse to accomplish the same goal?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

If there are any other details required, we'll be more than happy to provide them.

We can send images and files as necessary, but this account does not have permissions because it is new.

Comment: C#... We just finished writing a parser and edited our files to work with the new method constructors. We have tested the solution and as of now, there are no errors. I am not sure if you still plan on resolving the issue differently or dropping the issue. With our latest fixes however, it seems that the issue can be closed unless there have been any other reports on the issue.

Thanks for your support with this and our other issues

Comment: Am I right that you use fitSharp plugin ?